# What kind of data model should I use to store historical data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, data-modeling, facebook-graph-api, devise, omniauth

I'm hacking around with RoR to test devise and omniauth integration.
I now have a model with a User and a FacebookUser and TwitterUser that belong to a User.

I can now store data from the Graph API or Twitter API in my objects, but my question is about historical data. If I want to do a kind of twittercounter.com and store history of followers, tweets, etc. What is the best practice to do that ?

What kind of data model ? How often should I update the data and what part should I keep ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should never store a complete copy of an updated row.

In general, most likely you'll stick with approach that implies saving changes as revision control systems do: saving action and differences.

There is a model of saving history of table in another table. You can implement it in your app with little modifications. You can find more in this [great read](http://database-programmer.blogspot.com/2008/07/history-tables.html).

Comment: Thanks for the source article. About the best timing perspective. Should I update multiple times per day and then just concatenate all the data on a single line per day ? (+40 tweets for 6th of January).

Comment: @maud I think, if you need not to call your history data often, it's ok. But you should think of some encoded string, like in XML or JSON, because maybe you'll have to store time of tweet, or some other relevant data.